# Stretch TeeChart knob's visible area to the whole TChart frame

Tags: delphi, teechart

Here is the standard knob gauge of TChart, of which only a sector is used:

[image: Conventional knob]

Here we see that a huge area of Chart is not used.

I would like to have following cropped and stretched display:

[image: Cropped and stretched knob sector]

Which parameters of TChart could I use to achieve this?

Comment: You can position any series through their `CustomBounds` (I don't think there is a direct support for what you want to get, as this series is circular and tries to occupy space proportionally).

Comment: @Victoria: Thank you. I was looking at `CustomBounds` property too and found that `Left`, `Top`, `Right` and `Bottom` are read-only. `Width`, `Height`, `SetLocation` do not influence position at all. It seems that I will be further using the ugly TPanel trick.

Comment: Yes, because it's of type `TRect`. Make a rectangle that you assign to it (try e.g. `Series1.CustomBounds := Rect(0, 0, Chart1.ClientWidth, Chart1.ClientHeight * 2);` from the chart's `OnResize` event).

Comment: You're welcome! Steema actually shows kind of this way in [this example](https://github.com/Steema/TeeChart-VCL-samples/blob/master/TeeNew/KnobGauge_Series.pas) (coincidentally for `TKnobGauge`).